# l20n.js - how to access localization sub-entities from javascript

Tags: javascript, localization, l20n

In this example, I can see how to access the variables inside an LOL resource

```
<brandName {
  nominative: "Firefox",
  genitive: "Firefoksa",
  dative: "Firefoksowi",
  accusative: "Firefoksa",
  instrumental: "Firefoksem",
  locative: "Firefoksie"
}>

<about "O {{ brandName.locative }}">
```

However, I also want to be able to do something similar in javascript, for example:

```
document.l10.get('brandName.nominative');
```

This doesn't work for me though. I debugged a bit, but I feel like I'm wasting time and there's probably a simple way to do this already. Is there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible in L20n, because as a developer, you can't know for sure that `nominative` will be defined in all languages.  Read on to find out why.

In English, your example may very well look like this:

```
<brandName "Firefox">
<about "About {{ brandName }}">
```

There isn't any `.nominative` to ask for this time around!

L20n is all about asymmetry.  One variant of a string in English may correspond to 4 variants in German, 7 in Polish and 16 in Hungarian.  There is a social contract between the developer and L20n:  if the developer asks for a value of an entity called `brandName`, L20n will return a string that can be used in the UI.  All the work that is done to get that string is hidden from the developer and might differ depending on the language and the logic that the localizers built.

Depending on what you want to achieve, you might find the following two constructs helpful:

- [default values](http://l20n.org/learn/default-values-for-dictionaries/) can be used to indicate the default key to return if you don't ask for any specific one.  In the example from your question, you could define `nominative` as the default by putting an asterisk next to it, like so:

  ```
  <brandName {
   *nominative: "Firefox",
    genitive: "Firefoksa",
    dative: "Firefoksowi",
    accusative: "Firefoksa",
    instrumental: "Firefoksem",
    locative: "Firefoksie"
  }>
  <about "O {{ brandName.locative }}">
  ```

  When you now try to retrieve the translation of `brandName` in JavaScript, you'll get the value of the `nominative` key, "Firefox":

  ```
  document.l10.get('brandName');
  // "Firefox"
  ```
- [attributes](http://l20n.org/learn/attributes/) can be added to entities to store metadata, like so:

  ```
  <brandName "Firefox"
   accesskey: "F"
  >
  ```

  Note that attributes are different from dictionary values.  In the above example, the value of `brandName` is a simple string, "Firefox".  The `brandName` entity has an extra attribute, `accesskey` whose value is "F".  You can access attributes with [`getEntity`](https://github.com/l20n/l20n.js/blob/1.0.0b3/README.md#ctxgetentityid-string-ctxdata-object):

  ```
  document.l10.getEntity('brandName');    
  // { value: "Firefox", attributes: { accesskey: "F" } }
  ```

Comment: Stas, thanks for your help.  
  
Re: There isn't any .nominative to ask for this time around!    

It seems like this would be a good case for it to use the default value, in this case the only value. Maybe I should use attributes? For example: <firefox "Firefox" plural:"Firefoxes">. This it seems I will be able to access via javascript.

Comment: I'm not sure that would be the best solution.  I'd recommend against hardcoding plurals in the way you mentioned.  Some languages might use two or three different plural forms (e.g. in Polish: "2 Firefoksy", "5 Firefoksów").  What is the use-case that you have in mind?  Maybe there's another way of doing what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Staś, is there a way to access entity attributes from within HTML, not using JS. e.g. `<span data-l10n-id="brandName::accesskey"></span>`

Comment: Public entity attributes map to HTML attributes, so an element with `data-l10n-id="brandName"` will gain a new `accesskey` attribute if the `brandName` entity defines it.  Do you have a particular use-case in mind which isn't satisfied by this behavior?